# Different header layout Firefox vs Chrome in wordpress header

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, header

I'm working to install a secondary menu above my header image on a wordpress site and I'm getting different layouts in Firefox 24.0 and Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m, Wordpress 3.6.1.

Check out this test site to see the differences at the very top of the page, where Firefox "overlays" the top menu over the header and Chrome pushes the header down:

http://puckpros.edkatzman.com

The pages look the same if I remove the new menu, not surprisingly.

I have examined the page with Firebug and the Chrome tools and can't find the css that might be doing this.

On a side note, I want the top menu to be flush with the top of the page. I can't see anywhere in the css that it would cause a margin or padding at the top, but it's displaying about 22px from the top.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the tags using the metrics meter in Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: I looked up the metrics meter in the Dev tools, but the screens there don't look like what I see on my machine -- there is no metrics choice that I can find. I tried Chrome Canary to see if they were there but didn't find "metrics"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues that are causing that.

First thing - your menu has margin. I see that in your style.css you have the following:

```
.header-navigation ul {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Just change it to this:

```
.header-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

After you change that, you will still have your heading on top saying "Hockey Skills Training for North Shore Chicago" - you currently have "line-height: 1px;" which makes the heading squish itself.

You should either remove the heading completely(it is probably in your theme's header.php file) or move it after the opening tag for `<div id="header" class="grid-100 clearfix">` and then add this in your style.css(line 485):

```
h1.title {
    color: #000;
    padding: 3px 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

This way the heading will be actually visible and won't mess with your menu.

EDIT:

To make your navigation stay on top of the image, I would advise you to make it absolute. I believe that Chrome is rendering the navigation properly(I might be wrong as well). Any way, just change the entry on line 630 to this:

```
.header-navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
}
```

That should make sure that the navigation is always on top of your header image.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my problem of the top menu not being at the top of the page, but I still have a display difference between Chrome and Firefox, in that Chrome is putting the menu above the header but Firefox puts it in the header, which is what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer to make sure that your navigation will always be on top of the header image.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works the same in Chrome and Firefox and I can absolutely position my red button over the header image.